# Superuser is not permitted to login

Tags: postgresql

I created a superuser portal with the following command

```
create role portal with superuser password 'portal'
```

When I tried to login into postgres with portal user I am getting the following error in rails.

```
FATAL:  role "portal" is not permitted to log in
```

I can't follow what is going on.

of course I can alter user with login command to enable portal user to login. I would like to understand why super user can't login.

Comment: Because a `role` can never log in. You should have used `create user` if you want something that can log in.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name To be precise, there is no difference between a role and a user but there is between `CREATE ROLE` and `CREATE USER`, see Craig's answer.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You didn't specify the `LOGIN` right:

```
ALTER ROLE portal WITH LOGIN;
```

If you use `CREATE USER` instead of `CREATE ROLE` the `LOGIN` right is granted automatically; otherwise you must specify it in the `WITH` clause of the `CREATE` statement.

Superusers do not inherently have the `LOGIN` right; a permissions check is still performed for superuser for this right. The reason for this is so that you can have a superuser role that you can `SET ROLE` to, but cannot be connected as directly.

Answer (score 5):

```
CREATE ROLE 'portal' WITH LOGIN SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'portal';
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Your answer lacks an explanation - if you look around, good answers always tell you not only _what_ but also _why_ to do.  With this in view, what does your answer add to the one from Craig?